# Db2 SQL Select rows with excluding rows based on large number of data

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

I have following query to fetch data from table for reporting which excludes based on a condition

```
Select  ACCOUNTNO, EFFECTIVE_DATE, RATEPERCENTAGE
  FROM  TESTXY.ACCINFODET
WHERE
  EFFECTIVE_DATE > '2021-01-01'
AND ACCOUNTNO NOT IN 
(
00000005367890,
00000005378912,
00000007326741,
.
.
.
.
00000089237410,
)

ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO;
```

Exclude condition data ranges from 600 to 2K account number
can you please advice the best way to try

Many Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of the ACCOUNTNO column?  If it is a CHAR or VARCHAR (so a String) then you need to put the ACCOUNTNO values in quotes... So ACCOUNTNO NOT IN ( '00000005367890','00000005378912'...)

Comment: What is the issue with your query?  Your question seems lack a question.

Comment: This query works fine. am looking for better way to run this, 
in terms of db2 performance
Also, Exclude condition is bound change for every report. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Load the account numbers to be excluded in to a separate, single column table, then use a sub select in your *not in* clause:

```
...
AND ACCOUNTNO NOT IN 
( SELECT * FROM TESTXY.EXCLACCTNOS )
```

Warning: Not tested.